# Error 403: I got 403 error when i submit the form in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

when i submit the form server give me a 403 error. when i insert special characters in textarea.

**Blade file:**

```
<form action="submit_error" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Title</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="title" placeholder="Write your question">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group mt-4">
       <label for="">Description</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" id="" rows="3" name="description" placeholder="Write Your problem in detail"></textarea>
   </div>
   <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.19.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label mt-4">What did you try?</label>
   <textarea name="err_code" placeholder="Write your code"></textarea>
   <script>
       CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
   </script>
   <script>
       CKEDITOR.replace( 'err_code' );
   </script>
   <div class="form-group mt-4">
        <label for="">Tag</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="tag" placeholder="Add one tag about your query ex:Php">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Post Error</button>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public function submit_error(Request $request)
    {
        $all_data =  $request->all();
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $user_name = User::where('id',$user_id)->value('name');
        $slug = str_slug($all_data['title']);
        
        $tag_find = DB::table('tags')->where('tags',$all_data['tag'])->exists();
        
        if($tag_find != '1'){
            $tag_find = DB::table('tags')->insert([
                'tags' => $all_data['tag']
                ]);
        }

         
        $askerror = AskError::create([
            'user_name' => $user_name,
            'title' => $all_data['title'],
            'description' => $all_data['description'],
            'err_code' => $all_data['err_code'],
            'tag' => $all_data['tag'],
            'slug' => $slug
        ]);
        

        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
```

when i insert special characters in textarea then i got a 403 error. so, how to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"? What does the error message contain?

Comment: I insert !@<>{}%$ this types of special characters but i got 403 forbidden from server side . and i insert normal values then it work properly.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Do you validate the input anywhere?

Comment: I don't have an any idea about this error. I have check apache access log but it is all ok.

Comment: add `extraAllowedContent` for CKEditor

Comment: Well, give us more information. We are getting "-" for a bad answer and your question has parts of the code and that is it. Should I make a local website with your code to see what is wrong?

Comment: How to add extraAllowedContent? Please tell me in detail  @AbdullaNilam

Comment: textarea name="err_code" @AbdullaNilam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Input you need to allow *special characters*, then just add this parameter to it

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'description', {
    allowedContent: '!@<>{}%$'
});
```

or you can use it in `config`

```
config.extraAllowedContent
```

---

Read [`extraAllowedContent()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraAllowedContent) and [`allowedContent()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-allowedContent)

Answer (score 0):

Your form action attribute is not correct.
Change from

```
<form action="submit_error" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="{{ route('submit_error') }}" method="POST">
```

Also make sure you have added the route name on routes/web.php file like this sample.

```
Route::post('submit_error', 'YourController@submit_error')->name('submit_error');
```

Comment: already i tried that. it does't work.